# Find specific results from aggregation / Filter result of aggregation again?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The part of the data I'm working with right now is a datetime stamp. I would like to find all data for the current date, and then iterate through my array of 15-minute-interval timestamps to add each point of data to my `PyPlot`.

My initial aggregation is:

```
qryData = collection.aggregate([
{
"$addFields":
{
    "year": {"$year": {"$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$timestamp", "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"}}},
    "month": {"$month": {"$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$timestamp", "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"}}},
    "day": {"$dayOfMonth": {"$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$timestamp", "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"}}},
    "hour": {"$hour": {"$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$timestamp", "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"}}},
    "minute": {"$minute": {"$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$timestamp", "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"}}},
}
},
{
"$match":
{
    "year": dateToChart.year,
    "month": dateToChart.month,
    "day": dateToChart.day,
    "name": city
}
}
])
```

This aggregation achieves getting me all objects for the current date. I thought that I could then, say something like `qryData.find({"hour": hour})` inside of a loop to look through the results of my aggregation for the matching hour value, but I believe that `qryData` is a `Command Cursor`, and I couldn't find any methods to filter data from it.

I tried to run my aggregation inside of a `for` loop, and add my `hour` and `minute` values to the `$match` part of the aggregation, but querying/aggregating from the entire database each time like this made the operation extremely slow.

The other method I thought of was to iterate through `qryData`, then iterate through my array of time values, and if the values match, add them to an array, something like:

```
for results in qryData:
    for time in times:
        if qryData["hour"] = time.hour:
            filteredData.append(results)
```

While this method does work, it doesn't feel like the right or best way to do this, so I'm wondering how I should go about finding the specific result(s) from the return of an aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

That aggregation query will be worse than a collection scan.  It must first load every document in the collection, then extract the `timestamp` string, and perform 5 separate date conversion on the string.

If you have a year's worth of data at 1-minute intervals, that would be reading around 500k documents, and performing around 2.5 million date calculations just to get past the first stage.

If your date strings are in the form "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" they will naturally sort in chronological order with a lexicographical sort.

That means you could find all of the entries for 1 Sep with

```
{$match:{
   timestamp:{
      $gte: "2021-09-01",
      $lt: "2021-09-02"
   }
}}
```

That change would completely cut out the date calculations.

If you also create an index on the `timestamp` field, it would be able to scan the index, and only need to fetch the 1440 documents matching the day, instead of reading every document in the collection.

If you actually need the individual parts of the date for later in the pipeline, use [$dateToParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/#-datetoparts--aggregation-) to extract them all at once.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll be sure to switch over to this optimization. As far as finding my individual times from the results for the entire day, do I continue using my for loop method in the question, or can/should I use a PyMongo method to filter the results a second time?

Comment: Interestingly, adding this optimization (just the change to `aggregate()`, haven't added the index yet) actually made the program slower (~4 seconds longer for 24 hours of data every 15 minutes). Upon investigating it, running the `aggregate()` function was much quicker (~0.1sec -> ~0.02sec), but, without using `$addFields`, the code `if results["hour"] == curHour` had to become `if datetime.strptime(results["timestamp"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').hour == curHour`  and the for loop operation went from ~1.5sec to ~2.5sec.